How to setup breakout specific rules for Altium
I have some clearance rules between differential pairs that require more separation then the pitch of the actual component being used. I'd like to be able to "violate" that rule for a short period during breakout. How do I setup clearance rules that only apply within certain areas or lengths in Altium?

